# Trying to use filter parameter with C# PowerBI V2 API GetGroupsAsync()

Tags: c#, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I'm trying to select a PowerBI Embedded Group using the $filter parameter with **GetGroupsAsync()**

Currently I am using Microsoft Power BI Version 2 APIs with C#

This is the method I'm trying to use:

```
public static System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.Models.ODataResponseListGroup> GetGroupsAsync (this Microsoft.PowerBI.Api.V2.IGroups operations, string filter = null, Nullable<int> top = null, Nullable<int> skip = null, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken = null);
```

I can retrieve all the Power BI Groups using the below line, so I am confident the rest of my code is functioning

```
var groups = await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync();
```

But how does this $filter parameter need to be formatted to retrieve only one?

I found some Power BI API Version: v1.0 REST documentation

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/power-bi/groups/getgroups

I just need to match the Group Id GUID in the $filter, I tried the line below with no success

```
var groups = await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync($"id eq '{workspaceId.ToString()}'");
```

Has anyone been able to get this $filter parameter working with the Power BI Version 2 APIs and C#?

I would prefer not to resort to retrieving all the Groups and filtering within C# if the GetGroupsAsync() $filter parameter is available.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your example and it worked fine for me. I've used latest PowerBI.Api SDK.
You can use Fiddler and see the request that being sent.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```cs
Guid workspaceId = default(Guid);
ODataResponseListGroup workspacesList = new ODataResponseListGroup();
string workspaceFilter;

workspaceFilter = $"id eq '{workspaceId.ToString()}'";
workspacesList = await client.Groups.GetGroupsAsync(filter: workspaceFilter);
```